# Scale some object but not others in a Fabric group?

Tags: fabricjs

I have a group that contains a text object and a rectangle object. When the group is scaled I want the rectangle object to change size but the text object to remain the same size.

Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I tried lockScalingX and lockScalingY on the text object but that caused the entire group to not be scalable. I also tried setting the scale on the text object in the object:scaling event but it appears the scale actually changes on the group object.

Comment: Yes, observe "object:scaling" event on a group, and change its child (text object) scaleX/scaleY proportionally.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get that to work in the group scaling event using the setScaleX/Y methods for some reason the .scale() method didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematics! to the rescue!

look the fiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/w64bsnon/2/

```js
  var line;
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  canvas.on({
    'object:scaling': function(p){
     console.log('p',p.target.ScaleX )
      //p.target._objects[0].scaleX = p.target.scaleX
      //p.target._objects[0].scaleY = p.target.scaleY
      
      //p.target.scaleX = 1
      //p.target.scaleY = 1
   if (p.target.scaleX < 1)
       p.target._objects[1].scaleX = 1 + (1 -p.target.scaleX )
      else
       p.target._objects[1].scaleX = 1 / (p.target.scaleX)
      if (p.target.scaleY < 1)
       p.target._objects[1].scaleY = 1 + (1 -p.target.scaleY)
      else
       p.target._objects[1].scaleY = 1 / (p.target.scaleY)
  
      canvas.renderAll()
    },
  });
  
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({top: 110, left:110, height: 100, width: 100, fill:'#ccc'})
  
   var text = new fabric.IText('pepe',{text: 'pepe',top: 110, left:110, height: 100, width: 100, fill:'#000'})
  
  var group = new fabric.Group([rect,text])
  
  canvas.add(group)
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: another solution changing the width and height to maintain the borders and text of the group http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/qs0ywh8k/1/